# How to get SignalR Connection to Respect Session Timeout

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Using SignalR, it's designed to maintain a long-running connection to the web server.  However, I have a scenario where the SignalR connection maintains an open connection to the web server, long after the ASP.Net session has expired.  This happens even though neither the client nor the server is sending an data.

How can I set things up so that once the Asp.net session expires, the SignalR connection terminates, freeing up connections on the server?

This is desired because the web servers run on a load balancer, and when taking a server out of the rotation, we need the # of current connections to generally represent the number of active sessions - not SignalR connections that are still kicking just because user left browser open.

Comment: I thought about tapping into the hub authorization mechanism to ensure session is active, but that's kind of kludgy - especially since this doesn't require authentication at all.  The other idea I had was to let the clients themselves terminate the connection by monitoring session state, or by redirecting on session-end, but again - that feels more like a workaround than a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

SignalR Server does not allow to disconnect a particular client connection (this would be super useful). So the client is responsible to do that.

A workaround would be to add an event listener on the client and disconnect from there, i.e:

```
hubProxy.On<string>("YouAreUselesLetMeAlone", _ => connection.Dispose());
```

Obviously, to make this work you need a relation (ConcurrentDictionary?) of asp.net sessions <-> signalr connections, so you can call this method in the correct client when the asp.net session ends.